# C# the report definition has not been specified

Tags: c#, report, rdlc

I have a report tool that displays a lot of RDLC reports and I'm trying to add a new one and I can't see what I'm missing. I have the report included in the Project (I see it along with all the other RDLC reports in the Solution exporer).

This code for older reports works fine.

```
rvReports.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "paylocity.id.eStart.EditSummary.rdlc";
```

However, this gives me the error that the report definition has not been specified.

```
rvReports.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "paylocity.id.eStart.EditSummaryByMngr.rdlc";
```

I've double checked that the case is correct for the file I created. Can someone else see something I'm missing?

Comment: Or is there something else I should be looking at?

Comment: Try to add more details, where are you setting the source of the reports, etc

Comment: Check the documentation here [MSDN Creating Client Reporting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252067.aspx)

Comment: Are the rdlc files set as Embedded Resource?

Comment: Setting the datasource is the same for all the reports it is just different sql code that runs and that returns the data successfully. 

How can I check if they are embedded Resources? I've put them in the project folder and added them to the solution the same way I have for all the other reports. But it has been awhile since I've had to add a new report so I'm wondering if I missed a step somewhere.

Comment: Perhaps there's a typo, we won't know, more details would help

Comment: You wonder if you missed a step somewhere, but you don't show what steps you have taken

Comment: Step 1: Create the RDLC
Step 2: Move the RDLC to the project Folder
Step 3: Add the file to the Project
Step 4: copy existing code to add a new report changing only the Sql being run to populate the data table and the lines of code above
Step 5: try to run the report but get the error

Comment: Yeah, well that doesn't help much, I was expecting you to update your question with more CODE. I'll move on now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the file in Solution Explorer and open its Properties (`Right-click > Properties`, or `F4` or `Alt+Enter`). Ensure its *Build Action* is set to *Embedded Resource*

[image: BuildAction]

Comment: Thank you! that is exactly what I was missing. I knew it had to be something simple I was missing. This is the first report I've had to add as a new RDLC since upgrading VS. I guess the older version defaulted that value when I imported them.

Comment: And that's exactly what I asked you in the comments above

Comment: To be fair, he did then ask how to check if the report's Embedded, and nobody answered..